# Rails with dynamic asset-url background image from views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have to dynamically change the background-image of a div.

In my development environment, my solution was to do something like that:

```
# HTML.ERB
<style media="screen">
  .featured-box { background-image: url(<%= # Dynamic content %>); }
</style>
<div class="featured-box"></div>

# CSS.SCSS
.featured-box{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But when I push this into production (heroku) my assets are not loaded, I have to change `url(...)` to `asset-url(...)`.
It work great for the "fixed" `background-image` from the .css.scss file but not for them which are defined from the .html.erb file

Any idea on how to makes this work without using JS first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [image_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/image_path), which will add the asset digests for you.